# how can i sort my struct by x coordinate using std::sort

Tags: c++, oop

here is my struct:

```
class Pont{

private:

    int x, y;
public:

    Pont( int x=0, int y=0);
    int getX() const;
    int getY() const;
    void setX( int x );
    void setY( int y );
    void move( int nx, int ny);
};
```

and I fill my Pont type pontok :

```
while(n < N){

        int x=(rand()%2000);
        int y=(rand()%2000);
        Pont p(x,y);
        if(!letezike(p,n)){
            pontok[n]=p;
            ++n;
        }
```

and I've tried with this:

```
bool sorter(Pont const& lhs, Pont const& rhs) {

   if (lhs.getX() != rhs.getX())
        return lhs.getX() < rhs.getX();
}

std::sort(pontok[0], pontok[N], &sorter);
```

Comment: @billz, your edit made the code invalid, please be more careful

Comment: @JonathanWakely I didn't add anything, it's his original post. I only format the code

Comment: Check the edit history, you moved the `std::sort` call inside the `sorter` function! Oh actually I see you just added an extra brace at the end ... it still made it quite confusing

Comment: @JonathanWakely It's because there was an additional brace at the end. It's the askers fault! :)

Comment: ah yes, at the end of the line, well spotted

Comment: @JonathanWakely I was aware of your edit as well, was just thinking why you removed it. :)

Comment: I think it's ok now .. sorry for misreading your edit as introducing the problem!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove that `!=` check. It gives your program undefined behaviour if the `x` values are equal because the function will not reach a `return` statement.

```
bool sorter(Pont const& lhs, Pont const& rhs) {
    return lhs.getX() < rhs.getX();
}
```

If the `x` values are equal, this will return `false`, as it should do.

Also, your call to `std::sort` is incorrect. Assuming `pontok` is an array of points of size `N`, you need to do:

```
std::sort(pontok, pontok + N, &sorter);
```

`std::sort` takes an iterator range which point to the beginning and end of the sequence you want to sort. You were passing in two elements of your array.

Comment: I've removed it, but it still gives me the same errors...and it gives a lot of errors

Comment: thank you for your additional edit, it helped me. Now it is solved. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Your `sorter` function appears to return nothing when the X co-ordinates are equal, is that what you meant?!

It could be simply:

```
bool sorter(Pont const& lhs, Pont const& rhs) {
   return lhs.getX() < rhs.getX();
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, I've done this after sftrabbit helped me out, and it was useful. Thanks